# Solving NodeJs Refresh issue

Tags: node.js, connection

One of the disadvantage of NodeJs is single threading.  This causes the server to be unresponsive when for example you refresh the site rapidly multiple times.

I have been looking at a plugin for Nodejs will detect there are too many connections and return an error or refuse further connections from that connection.

I have found https://github.com/lloyd/node-toobusy, however, after loading the plugin, i'm running into issues where the assets of the sites are not getting loaded everytime.

Is there any other Nodejs modules that will solve the Too many connection issues in NodeJs?

Comment: This plugin sends error codes when it is too busy. Is it possible that it decides it's too busy when trying to access an asset?

Comment: the issue was that i was not trying to cache the assets, so every time a reload happens i was requesting the new assets.  I added Assets Caching in Node and that solved the issue.

Comment: Could you express this as an answer and mark it as solved? That way people in the future with similar issues can see what the solution was.

Comment: Single threaded is not an issue, it's actually what makes NodeJS so powerful. If your app is not loading after multiple refreshes, you may need to look into this, since this is not a common error with NodeJS and I have never heard of this happening. The issue is likely unrelated to NodeJS.